# Record Centre Mystery

Tags: records-center

In our record centres in our SharePoint 2010 farm each document that is transferred automatically by the expiration policy timer job is marked as modified by me - the primary site administrator. Now I am aware that there are accounts with the web submitters role that actually do the moving to the final destination in record centre. But at the end of the process it is not a web submitter account that ends up as the modified by - it's always me. So just recently I got tired of seeing my name so I decided it was time for change. I created a Sharepoint Administrator generic account and made that account  the primary site administrator for the record centre in question. Now here is the problem. After making the change my name continues to be the modified by for each document that is transferred. Getting desperate I removed all my access from the record centre but still all documents continued to modified  by me. My question is this does anyone know where the modified by role in record centre is defined because clearly it can't be the primary site administrator.

Comment: Could it be a workflow impersonating your account?

Comment: Yeah I had thought of that but what's moving documents out of the drop off library is not a custom workflow - it is straight out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved. It turns out the 'Modfied By' is determined by the account with the lowest user ids specified in the rule managers section of the content organizer setting. If no accounts are specified then the default 'modified by' is  the system account. So obvious but it took a dunce like me a week of testing to figure out. Wish Microsoft would document things better.

Answer (score 0):

There is another very useful way to manage the "Modified by" value; if routing succeeds, you can get the final file destination thanks to SendToOfficialFile output; and so you can update the field after the file has been moved.